# When adding li tags to the ul tag , the heading is getting disappered?

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bL1gdxth/2/

In the above jsfiddle once you click on Current Orders , it shows rows representing Orders .
When clicked on that particular Order link , data related to that Row will be shown , the issue i am facing is that the  Heading (Row) is getting disappered

Could anybody please help me how to resolve this

```
<div  class="currentOrdersWrapper">
        <a id="co_btn" class="currentOrdLink">Current Orders</a>
        <ul id="co_ul" class="currentOrdersUl" style="display:block">

        </ul>
    </div>


$(document).on('click', '#co_btn', function (event) {
    $("#co_ul").empty();
    var html = '<div id="co_row123" id_data="123" class="currentOrderRow">\
         <aside><b>Order No : </b>123</aside>\
         <aside><b>Vendor Name: </b>First Vendor</aside>\
      </div>\
   <div id="codetails123"  class="currentOrderDetailsWrap" style="height: 100px; display: none; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0980392);">\
   </div>';
    $("<li>" + html + "</li>").appendTo("#co_ul");

    var html2 = '<div id="co_row223" id_data="223" class="currentOrderRow">\
         <aside><b>Order No : </b>223</aside>\
         <aside><b>Vendor Name: </b>Second Vendor</aside>\
      </div>\
   <div id="codetails223"  class="currentOrderDetailsWrap" style="height: 100px; display: none; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0980392);">\
   </div>';

    $("<li>" + html2 + "</li>").appendTo("#co_ul");

    $("#co_ul").slideToggle();

});

$(document).on('click', '.currentOrderRow', function (event) {
    var orderid = $(this).attr("id_data");
    $("#co_row" + orderid).empty();
    if(orderid=='123')
    {
        var htmldiv = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"\
        <div class="orderTitle">FirstItem\
        </div>\
        </div>';
    }
    else if(orderid=='223')
    {
        var htmldiv = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"\
        <div class="orderTitle">SecondItem\
        </div>\
        </div>';
    }
    $("#co_row" + orderid).append(htmldiv);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are calling `$("#co_row" + orderid).empty();` in the click handler...

what you should do is if the item is present don't do anything like

```
$(document).on('click', '.currentOrderRow', function (event) {
    var orderid = $(this).attr("id_data");
    if($("#co_row" + orderid).find('.order-listdetails-wrap').length){
        return;
    };
    if(orderid=='123')
    {
        var htmldiv = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"\
<div class="orderTitle">FirstItem\
</div>\
</div>';
    }
    else if(orderid=='223')
    {
        var htmldiv = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"\
<div class="orderTitle">SecondItem\
</div>\
</div>';
    }
    $("#co_row" + orderid).append(htmldiv);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5rd54qr5/)

Comment: if you dont mind , why the   $("#co_row" + orderid).toggle(); is not working in the above fiddle ??

Comment: @PreethiJain where is it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5rd54qr5/2/ , i just modified the code in your jsfiddle . to achive togggle behaviour when clicked on the Order Row multiple times .

Answer (score 1):

Just change from display: block to display: none and it will work :) http://jsfiddle.net/bL1gdxth/3/

```
<div class="currentOrdersWrapper">  <a id="co_btn" class="currentOrdLink">Current Orders</a>

    <ul id="co_ul" class="currentOrdersUl" style="display:none;"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer , but I am still seeing the same behaviour . when clicked on Link Order 123 , the Link Order 123 is being hidden know .